# Can you change an inactive Form's text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text

I am wondering if it is possible to change an inactive `Form`'s text? The `Form` is `Inactive` because I have a `MessageBox` shown.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
private void ChangeFormText()
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.Text = "This doesn't work...";
}
```

But that doesn't work. I tried this:

```
private void ChangeFormText()
{
    this.Text = "This still doesn't work...";
}
```

And this doesn't work also. I have also tried this:

```
Form1 form = null;
public void ChangeFormText()
{
    form.Text = "And this won't work!";
}
```

But that throws an error.

This still doesn't work:

```
this.Text = "NOTHING WORKS";
```

Is there any way to change the `Inactive` `Form`'s `Text`?

Comment: `this.Text` will work (assuming `this` is the correct form).  Use the debugger to find out when it's running.  In particular, `MessageBox.Show()` is a blocking call.

Comment: this.Text DOES NOT WORK!!

Comment: Was the form active at the moment that you called the MsgBox? Can you supply us with some more code, so that we can see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MaartenKesselaers Yes, the `Form` **WAS** active at the time the `MessageBox` was shown.

Comment: @MaartenKesselaers I am trying to change the `Form`'s `Text`. What do you mean "show us more code so we can see what you are trying to achieve" I am trying to change the `Form`'s `Text`...

Comment: @Dozer789 your `MessageBox` doesn't allow any code after `MessageBox.Show(...)` to be executed until the `MessageBox` is closed. You have to determine why and when you want to change the form text so that we can have a solution (we may have to use thread if it's needed).

Comment: @Dozer789 Can you post the code that you are running? Do you want to change the text while you are showing the MessageBox, because then we need to use King King's threading option.

Comment: @MaartenKesselaers I don't care if I show it after the `MessageBox` is closed, I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you add a printscreen of how your Form is shown? Is it possible that the form is within some other sort of container? Add a breakpoint at the moment where your program is designed to change the text and see if the 'this' object is the same as you expected it.

Comment: I got it figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `MessageBox` is shown - any code in the `Form` won't run. And you can't put code into a `MessageBox` (as far as I know).

But what you can do is use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which works asynchronously.

This works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        w.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(w_DoWork);
    }

    void w_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Invoke(new Action(doit));
    }

    void doit()
    {
        Text = "Changed";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        w.RunWorkerAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Random Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a TON!! This has helped me tremendously!!

Answer (score 2):

This is something you don't have to take care of.  The title bar of a window already paints with distinctive colors, any Windows user is familiar with it.  But you can, you have events for this:

```
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Text = "I miss you, come back soon";
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Text = "I'm back!  What can I do to help you today?";
    }
```

Unfortunately, not even the best intentions is going to stop that from being repetitive and annoying.  Don't tell the user what he already knows and expects.  Only tell him about the *surprises*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change `Text` before calling `MessageBox.Show(...)`, just do it normally. If you want to change `Text` after calling `MessageBox.Show(...)` you can use `BeginInvoke` to show the message box like this:

```
 BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { MessageBox.Show("OK"); }));     
 Text = "????";
```